# CORS issue when requesting mocks after upgrading from Testcafe 1.2.1 to 2.5.1-rc.1

Tags: testing, cors, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I've recently upgraded a project from Testcafe `1.2.1` to `2.5.1-rc.1`.

I have a simple test which previously ran successfully before the upgrade which now fails with this error message:

*Error*

```
1) Cannot obtain information about the node because the specified selector does not match any node in the DOM tree.

 > | Selector('.review__title')
         |   .nth(0)
```

*Review.feature.ts*

```
const startUrl = `${config.host}${ProductDetails.path}`;

fixture("Product Details Reviews")
  .requestHooks(...defaultMocks, getCategoriesTreeMock, getCustomerProfileMock)
  .page(startUrl)
  .beforeEach(async t => {
    await t.navigateTo(startUrl);
  });

test.skip.meta(testTarget.ALL).requestHooks(getProductsBySeoUrlMock(), fetchReviewsMock)(
  "Submits inappropriate feedback",
  async t => {
    const page = new ProductDetails();
    await page.clickReviewsTab();
    await page.clickReportInappropriateFeedback(0);
    await page.enterInappropriateFeedback("This review is inappropriate");
    await page.submitInappropriateFeedback();
    await t
      .expect(page.getSubmitInappropriateFeedbackSuccessMessage().textContent)
      .contains("successfully submitted feedback");
  }
);
```

```
import { RequestMock } from "testcafe";

const isFetchReviews = ({ url, method }: RequestData) => url.includes("data/reviews.json") && method === "get";

const isSubmitInappropriateFeedback = ({ url, method }: RequestData) =>
  url.includes("data/submitfeedback.json") && method === "post";

export const submitInappropriateFeedbackMock = RequestMock()
  .onRequestTo(isSubmitInappropriateFeedback)
  .respond(
    {
      Locale: "en_US",
      Errors: [],
      Feedback: { Inappropriate: { AuthorId: "123", ReasonText: "Some profanity" } },
      Form: [],
      FormErrors: {},
      SubmissionId: null,
      Data: {},
      TypicalHoursToPost: null,
      AuthorSubmissionToken: null,
      HasErrors: false,
    },
    200,
    { "access-control-allow-origin": "*" }
  );

export const fetchReviewsMock = RequestMock()
  .onRequestTo(isFetchReviews)
  .respond(
    {
      Locale: "en_US",
      Includes: {},
      Errors: [],
      Results: [
        {
          UserNickname: "Tester",
          Rating: 4,
          ReviewText: "Terrible product",

        },
      ],
      TotalResults: 16,
      Limit: 10,
      HasErrors: false,
      Offset: 0,
    },
    200,
    { "access-control-allow-origin": "*" }
  );
```

```
export function getProductsBySeoUrlMock(seoUrl: string, resBody: object = response) {
  return RequestMock()
    .onRequestTo(
      ({ url, method }: RequestData) =>
        url.includes(
          `/reviews`
        ) && method === "get"
    )
    .respond(resBody, 200, {
      "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
    });
}
```

On closer inspection, it appears the selector is failing because the component fails to render because the request receives a CORS error.

```
Access to fetch at 'http://192...' from origin 'http://192...' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-encoding is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Can someone help me understand why this is happening after the upgrade? I can't seem to find anything in the TestCafe documentation.

How do I fix this?

Comment: What does your browser's Console tab say? Does it contain a CORS error? If so, edit your question and add the error message there.

Comment: Good point, I've updated the question with the console error. It looks like, I need to update the access-control-allow-headers header property some where. Still can't understand why this has changed after upgrading...